# Как сделать uwp стиль на tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, uwp

У меня есть код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
from threading import Thread
import time
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import base64
import random
import config
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

root = Tk()
root.title("EasyNotepad")
root.geometry("800x300")
root.option_add("*tearOff", FALSE)

style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme("winnative")

tip = Label(root, text="Введите текст:", font=('Segoe UI', 18, "bold"))
tip.place(y=0)
text_font = ('Segoe UI', 14)

user_text = Text(root, font=text_font, background="#000000", foreground="#FFFFFF")
user_text.place(y=30, height=290)
user_text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
user_text.insert(0.1, f"Добро пожаловать в EasyNotepad!\nСохраните или откройте файл во вкладке \"Файл\"; Настройте вид текста во вкладке \"Редактировать\"; Включите автосохранение во вкладке \"Автосохранение\".\nПоддержите автора донатом на ЮМани: {config.yoomoney}")

# НОВОЕ ОКНО

def new_window():
    os.system("en.exe")
    print("Открытие окна: окно было успешно открыто")

# НОВОЕ ОКНО

# СОХРАНЕНИЕ / ОТКРЫТИЕ

def text_save():
    global user_text
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    if filepath != "":
        text = user_text.get("1.0", END)
        file = open(filepath, "w", encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(text)
        file.close
        mb.showinfo('Успешно!', 'Файл успешно сохранён!')

def text_open():
    global user_text
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if filepath != "":
        user_text.delete(0.1, END)
        file = open(filepath, "r", encoding='utf-8')
        text = file.read()
        user_text.insert(0.1, text)
        file.close
        mb.showinfo('Успешно!', 'Файл успешно прочитан!')

# СОХРАНЕНИЕ / ОТКРЫТИЕ

autosave_works = False

# АВТОСОХРАНЕНИЕ

def autosave_turn():
    global autosave_works
    autosave_works = True
    print(autosave_works)
    th = Thread(target=autosave)
    th.start()

def autosave_off():
    global autosave_works
    autosave_works = False
    print(autosave_works)

def autosave():
    global autosave_works
    while autosave_works == True:
        global user_text
        time.sleep(3)
        t = user_text.get(0.1, END)
        filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
        if filepath != "":
            text = user_text.get("1.0", END)
            file = open(filepath, "w", encoding='utf-8')
            file.write(text)
            file.close
            print("Автосохранение: всё исправно работает!")

# АВТОСОХРАНЕНИЕ

clearT = lambda x=0.1, y=END : user_text.delete(x, y)

# РАЗМЕРЫ ТЕКСТА

def px18():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 18)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def px10():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 10)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def px15():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 15)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def px24():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 24)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def own_size():
    global user_text
    
    wnd = Tk()
    wnd.title("EN")
    wnd.resizable(False,False)
    wnd.geometry("200x45")

    size = Entry(wnd)
    size.place(width=200)
    size.insert(0, "32")

    set_size = lambda x = 0 : user_text.configure(font=('Segoe UI', int(size.get())))

    submit = Button(wnd, text="Задать размер", command=set_size)
    submit.place(x=55, y=20)
    
    wnd.mainloop()

# РАЗМЕРЫ ТЕКСТА

# ЭФФЕКТЫ ТЕКСТА

def bold():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 14, 'bold')
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def italic():
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 14, 'italic')
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def underline_text():
    global user_text
    text_font = font.Font(size=14, underline=True)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def overstrike_text():
    global user_text
    text_font = font.Font(size=14, overstrike=True)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

def reset_font(): # Сброс
    global user_text
    text_font = ('Segoe UI', 14)
    user_text.configure(font=text_font)

# ЭФФЕКТЫ ТЕКСТА
    
actbg = "#000000"
actfg = "#FFFFFF"
bg = "#000000"
fg = "#161a1e"

# ЗАПУСК СКРИПТОВ

def python():
    global user_text
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    if filepath != "":
        text = user_text.get("1.0", END)
        file = open(filepath, "w", encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
        os.system(f"python {filepath}")
    
def cpp():
    global user_text
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    if filepath != "":
        text = user_text.get("1.0", END)
        file = open(filepath, "w", encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
        os.system(f"g++ {filepath} -o easynotepad")
        os.system(f"easynotepad.exe")

# ЗАПУСК СКРИПТОВ
    
# ГОТОВЫЕ СКРИПТЫ

def script01(): # Гипотеза Коллатца
    global user_text
    script = open('script/script1.py', "r", encoding='utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, script.read())
    script.close()
    print("Готовые скрипты: успешное чтение")

# ГОТОВЫЕ СКРИПТЫ

# МЕНЮ ШИФРОВАНИЯ

def readme_encrypt():
    mb.showwarning('Внимание!', 'При нажатии на одну из кнопок шифрования, весь текст в поле ввода будет зашифрован и текст будет заменён!!!')

def ascii85_encrypt():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.a85encode(t))

def base64_encrypt():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.b64encode(t))

def base32_encrypt():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.b32encode(t))

# МЕНЮ ШИФРОВАНИЯ
    
# МЕНЮ РАСШИФРОВАНИЯ

def base64_decode():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.b64decode(t))

def base32_decode():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.b32decode(t))

def ascii85_decode():
    global user_text
    t = bytes(user_text.get(0.1, END), encoding = 'utf-8')
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, base64.a85decode(t))

# МЕНЮ РАСШИФРОВАНИЯ

# ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ СПИСКОВ

elements = 0

def list_generator():
    global user_text, elements
    l_g = Tk()
    l_g.title('Генератор списков')
    l_g.resizable(False,False)
    l_g.geometry("300x100")

    elements = Entry(l_g)
    elements.place(width=300)
    elements.insert(0, "Введите количество элементов")

    generate = Button(l_g,text="Генерация", command=generation)
    generate.place(y=20)

def generation():
    global user_text, elements
    l = []
    for i in range(int(elements.get())):
        l.append(random.randint(0,9))
        user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, l)
    user_text.insert(0.1,"[")
    user_text.insert(END,"]")
    t = user_text.get(0.1, END)
    t = t.replace(" ", ",")
    user_text.delete(0.1, END)
    user_text.insert(0.1, t)

# ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ СПИСКОВ

encrypt_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
encrypt_menu.add_command(label="Ascii85", command=ascii85_encrypt)
encrypt_menu.add_command(label="Base64", command=base64_encrypt)
encrypt_menu.add_command(label="Base32", command=base32_encrypt)
encrypt_menu.add_command(label="README", command=readme_encrypt)

decode_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
decode_menu.add_command(label="Ascii85", command=ascii85_decode)
decode_menu.add_command(label="Base64", command=base64_decode)

generators_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
generators_menu.add_command(label="Генератор числовых списков", command=list_generator)

script_start_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
script_start_menu.add_command(label="Python", command=python)
script_start_menu.add_command(label="C++ (компилятор g++)", command=cpp)

scripts_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
scripts_menu.add_command(label="Гипотеза Коллатца", command=script01)

dev_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
dev_menu.add_cascade(label="Запуск скрипта", menu=script_start_menu)
dev_menu.add_cascade(label="Готовые скрипты (Python)", menu=scripts_menu)
dev_menu.add_cascade(label="Шифрование", menu=encrypt_menu)
dev_menu.add_cascade(label="Расшифровка", menu=decode_menu)
dev_menu.add_cascade(label="Генераторы", menu=generators_menu)

file_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command=text_save)
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command=text_open)
file_menu.add_command(label="Создать новое окно", command=new_window)

font_size_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="10px", command=px10)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="15px", command=px15)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="18px", command=px18)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="24px", command=px24)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="Свой", command=own_size)

weight_text_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label='Жирный', command=bold)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Наклонистый", command=italic)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Подчёркивание", command=underline_text)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Зачёркивание", command=overstrike_text)

font_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
font_menu.add_cascade(label="Размеры текста", menu=font_size_menu)
font_menu.add_cascade(label="Эффекты текста", menu=weight_text_menu)
font_menu.add_command(label="Сбросить настройки", command=reset_font)

edit_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Очистить", command=clearT)
edit_menu.add_cascade(label="Шрифт", menu=font_menu)

autosave_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg,font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
autosave_menu.add_command(label="Включить", command=autosave_turn)
autosave_menu.add_command(label="Выключить", command=autosave_off)

def about():
    about_wnd = Tk()
    about_wnd.title("О программе")
    about_wnd.geometry("300x100")
    about_wnd.resizable(False,False)

    authorL = Label(about_wnd, text=f"Сделано {config.author} в 2024 году\nНа языке программирования Python\nПрограмма бесплатна на 100%\nВерсия:{config.version}")
    authorL.pack()

    donateL = Label(about_wnd, text=f"ЮMoney для донатов: {config.yoomoney}")
    donateL.pack()

    about_wnd.mainloop()

main_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg, font=('Segoe UI', 16), foreground=fg)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Редактировать", menu=edit_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Автосохранение", menu=autosave_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Режим разработчика", menu=dev_menu)
main_menu.add_command(label="О программе", command=about)

root.config(menu=main_menu, background="#486C00")
root.mainloop()
```

как мне сделать приложение в uwp стиле?

Comment: https://discuss.python.org/t/can-tkinter-support-a-function-similar-to-acrylic-under-win10/11247